# IONIC 4: cancelButtonText of ion-searchbar is not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Using IONIC 4 ion-searchbar, I am trying to add cancelButtonText as below which it is not working.

```
//first way
    <ion-searchbar showCancelButton="true" cancelButtonText="Clear"></ion-searchbar>

//second way
    <ion-searchbar showCancelButton cancelButtonText="Clear"></ion-searchbar>
```

Can anyone please provide any solution for this ?

Comment: which platform you are testing? Android or IOS

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan I am trying on Android.

Comment: have you tried this `<ion-searchbar showCancelButton cancelButtonText="Custom Cancel"></ion-searchbar>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing the `cancelButtonText` in Android platform it wont be working because in the ionic documentation of `ion-searchbar` they have mentioned that the `cancelButtonText` is only for the `IOS` platform and they have given the mode as `IOS` or `md` for the attributes.So the attributes will be worked based on the mode.

Also I have created the stackblitz so that you can check the example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-n93fh7?file=pages%2Ftabs%2Ftabs.html

When you change the mode to `md` in the example `cancelButtonText` is not working.

You can refer the documentation here [ion-searchbar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/searchbar)